# Unable to Generate Address Endpoint Blockcypher

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, php

I am trying to generate an address using Blockcyphers Address Endpoint using cUrl.

```
- https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/addrs?token=eth
```

But it returns this error - "Endpoint not found. Please check your URL for typos and make sure you're using the correct HTTP method (GET, POST, etc)."

Im guessing im doing something wrong where it needs 'token'..

```
- https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/addrs?token=YOURTOKEN

  $requesturl='https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/addrs?token=eth';
  $ch=curl_init($requesturl);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $cexecute=curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  echo $cexecute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate to this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961123/php-curl-post-api

Used Parithiban answer and switched GET to POST